# Using variables when executing single command in PSQL

Tags: sql, bash, psql, postgresql-9.3

When using PSQL's variables, I can run it as follows:

```sh
psql -d database -v var="'123'"
```

And I will then have access to the variable `var` when I type the following in the PSQL terminal:

```sql
select * from table where column = :var;
```

This variable feature also works when the SQL is read from a file:

```sh
psql -d database -v var="'123'" -f file.sql
```

But when I try to run the SQL as a single command:

```sh
psql -d database -v var="'123'" -c "select * from table where column = :var;"
```

I can't access the variable and get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

Is it possible to pass variables to single SQL commands in PSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, as `man psql` explains, the `-c` command is limited to SQL that "contains no psql-specific features":

> ```
>    -c command, --command=command
>        Specifies that psql is to execute one command string, command, and then exit. This is useful in shell
>        scripts. Start-up files (psqlrc and ~/.psqlrc) are ignored with this option.
>
>        command must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no
>        psql-specific features), or a single backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands
>        with this option. To achieve that, you could pipe the string into psql, for example: echo '\x \\ SELECT
>        * FROM foo;' | psql. (\\ is the separator meta-command.)
> ```

It looks like I can do what I want by passing in the SQL using stdin:

```
echo "select * from table where column = :var;" | psql -d database -v var="'123'"
```